# Subscription Status: An error has occurred during report processing

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I'm having difficulty sending auto generated e-mails via SSRS. I'm getting a vague error that states "An error has occurred during report processing.". I've detailed the full error below. Does anyone know some of the possible reasons why I would be getting this error?

Here are examples of the Shared Dataset Properties:

[image]

[image]

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
library!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: i INFO: Schedule 3d1ac939-3fb6-4313-9e04-bce6353a6825 executed at 07/11/2019 10:18:01.
schedule!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: Creating Time based subscription notification for subscription: a9d6e90a-84fc-439d-b715-49f7479cf69d
library!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: i INFO: Schedule 3d1ac939-3fb6-4313-9e04-bce6353a6825 execution completed at 07/11/2019 10:18:01.
library!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 1722, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
processing!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: e ERROR: An exception has occurred in data set 'DS_Example'. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
processing!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: i INFO: DataPrefetch abort handler called for Report with ID=. Aborting data sources ...
processing!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
processing!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: w WARN: Data source ' Data source for shared dataset': Report processing has been aborted.
processing!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
library!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: i INFO: Initializing EnableExecutionLogging to 'True'  as specified in Server system properties.
notification!WindowsService_9!14c0!07/11/2019-10:18:01:: e ERROR: Error occured processing subscription a9d6e90a-84fc-439d-b715-49f7479cf69d: An error has occurred during report processing.
```

I ran the procedure that the data set reference. The data generates without any issues. I've created subscriptions for existing reports and they all executed without error. I've also check the connections to confirm that it wasn't a credential issue but it connected without error.

The subscription should generate a daily report to specified users.

Comment: Your procedure name looks odd.  Is it intended to have spaces?  Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/troubleshooting/rsserverconfigurationerror-reporting-services-error?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry, I blocked out the name. It should be "P_Example_Dataset"

Comment: Ah, I see.  Have you tested the connection for the data source?  Are there any other errors in the log before or after the ones you posted?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also updated the error log above to include additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the permissions needed to be granted for the service account database and table. The issue has been resolved!

Answer (score 1):

The Win32 error 1722 is the key to this error message.  It's an RPC server not available error.  Microsoft has a KB article addressing this exact issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/842423/a-call-to-the-authzinitializecontextfromsid-api-function-fails-during